# Определить сколько раз в строке встречается заданное слово

Tags: c++, алгоритм, строки

Если введённая строка состоит из одного слова и это же слово присвоить `char word [20]`, все работает. Во всех других случаях нeт.

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>
#include <conio.h>
#include <string.h>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int n = 0;

    cout << "Input sentence" << endl;
    char sent[80];
    cin.getline(sent, 80);
    cout << "Input word" << endl;
    char word[20];
    cin.getline(word, 20);
    char* tmp = word;
    while ((tmp = strstr(tmp, sent)) != NULL)
    {
        n++;
        tmp++;
    }
    cout<<"The number of same words "<< n<<endl;

    _getch();
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Во-первых, у вас указан неверный порядок аргументов в вызове функции `strstr`

```
strstr(tmp, sent)) 
       ^^^^^^^^^^
```

Этот вызов определяет, содержится ли предложение, указанное переменной `sent`, в слове, указанным переменной `word`.

Отсюда бессмысленно увеличивать указатель `tmp`

```
tmp++;
```

так как изначально он был задан как

```
char* tmp = word;
```

Вы должны увеличивать не переменную `tmp`, а изменять указатель в строке `sent`. Ниже приведена демонстрационная программа.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>

int main() 
{
    const size_t N = 80;
    char sent[N];
    const size_t M = 20;
    char word[M];

    std::cout << "Input sentence: " << std::endl;
    std::cin.getline( sent, sizeof( sent ) );

    std::cout << "Input word: " << std::endl;
    std::cin.getline( word, sizeof( word ) );

    size_t n = 0;
    size_t len = std::strlen( word );

    for ( const char *src = sent; 
          ( src = std::strstr( src, word ) ) != nullptr; 
          src += len )
    {
        n++;
    }

    std::cout << "The number of same words " << n << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Вывод программы на консоль может выглядеть следующим образом

```
Input sentence: I like C++ and I like C
Input word: like
The number of same words 2
```

В этой программе я смещаю указатель в строке  `sent` на длину найденной строки `word`, то есть искомые слова в строке не должны пересекаться. Если вы хотите убрать это ограничение, то есть подсчитывать число совпадений строки `word` в строке `sent`, то в `sent` смещайте указатель не на длину строки `word`, а на единицу, то есть вместо выражения

```
src += len
```

запишите

```
++src
```

Если вы хотите искать действительно отдельные слова, а не просто совпадения, то вам надо проверять, что найденное слово ограничено знаками пробелов или пунктуации.

Например, в этом случае программа может выглядеть следующим образом

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>
#include <cctype>

int main() 
{
    const size_t N = 80;
    char sent[N];
    const size_t M = 20;
    char word[M];

    std::cout << "Input sentence: " << std::endl;
    std::cin.getline( sent, sizeof( sent ) );

    std::cout << "Input word: " << std::endl;
    std::cin.getline( word, sizeof( word ) );

    size_t n = 0;
    size_t len = std::strlen( word );

    for ( const char *src = sent; 
          ( src = std::strstr( src, word ) ) != nullptr; src += len )
    {
        if ( not ( src != sent && std::isalnum( ( unsigned char )*( src - 1 ) ) ||
            std:: isalnum( ( unsigned char )*( src + len ) ) ) )
        {            
            n++;
        }           
    }

    std::cout << "The number of same words " << n << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Вы ищете в строке `tmp` подстроку `sent`, а надо бы наоборот...

```
char* tmp = sent;
while ((tmp = strstr(tmp,word)) != NULL)
```

И еще - вы ищете **подстроки**, а не слова, так что ища `кот`, вы найдете его в `котенке`... Это точно в правилах игры?

Answer (score 0):

Решение, конечно, сишное, а не плюсовое. Но раз уж в оригинальном коде подход именно такой...

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <errno.h>

const char DELIMITERS[] = "\t \n\v\b\r\"'`.,;";

static int word_count( const char *string, const char *word )
{
    char *token;
    int n = 0;
    char *copy = strdup( string );

    if( !copy ) {
        return -1;
    }

    token = strtok( copy, DELIMITERS );

    while( token ) {
        if( !strcmp( token, word ) ) {
            n++;
        }

        token = strtok( NULL, DELIMITERS );
    }

    free( copy );
    return n;
}

int main()
{
    int count = word_count( "I like C++ and I like C", "like" );

    if( count < 0 ) {
        printf( "Error: %s\n", strerror( errno ) );
    }
    else {
        printf( "%d\n", count );
    }

    return count < 0;
}
```